Angular service calling `import()`
I have an Angular application that has language files that are loaded at runtime using import('./en-us.json'). This works fine when the files are in the same folder but I want to put the service in the main application and call it from a library that has a component and it's own language files.
└── main-app
    ├── app.js
    ├── language-loader.service.js
    ├── en-us.json

└── library
    ├── library.js <-- will call language-loader.service.js with path to lib-en-us.json
    ├── lib-en-us.json

When library.js calls language-loader.service.js function that call import() the import fails. How pass in the path so it is relative to library.js?
I have tried using import.meta.url but the paths returned are absolute local ones e.g. c:\library\lib-en-us.json.
I'm aware I can declare the language files as assets and give an absolute path to them there but this does scale well to lots of language files from lots of libraries.
Is there some Webpack magic I need to do? Thanks.
